# Pass data to django view with ajax

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, post

I am very new to django and the whole world of jquery, ajax, etc.

I am having a page that when a function (javascript, jquery) function is run, I use the POST method to pass some data to my django view.

My jquery function is:

```
    function handleClick(e) {
        var myDataVariable = Variable
        var url = window.location.href
        var obj = {'Cellid': myDataVariable }
        $.ajax(
            {type:'POST',
             url: url,
             data: JSON.stringify(obj),
             contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {}
          });
    }
```

and in my django views I have:

```
    def Main(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            params = json.loads(request.body)
            Cellid = params['Cellid']
            CellData = cellData.cell_Data(int(Cellid))
        else:
            CellData =[]

        context = {
            'CellData':CellData,
        }

        return render(request, 'Main/Main.html', context)
```

Although the page works fine, when the function is called I am getting an error:

***Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /Main/Main***

Can someone please help me with this error? It is probably something simple but as I said I am very new to this and it is killing me! I would really appreciate a simple and easy to understand explanation.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must first extract your django CSRF token into jquery using this function:

```
// using jQuery to define CSRF token
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Then you can pass the csrftoken variable into your ajax request headers like so:

```
$.ajax({                   
        url: url,                    
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          data
        },
        headers: { "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken }.....
```

For some context on CSRF tokens: they are basically security tokens which are passed between POST api calls in your application which demonstrate that the request is being made from within the app and not from a potentially malicious third party

Hope this helps